# didReceiveMemoryWarning Crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, dealloc, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

-Using ARC

-I have 5 separate view controllers all subclassing a class I made called "UIViewControllerWithLoadingView" which subclasses UIViewController.

-In both the subclasses and superclass I allocate and deallocate properties like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *urlConnection;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.urlConnection=nil;
}
```

-Now when didReceiveMemoryWarning is called, the sub classes viewDidUnload method acts fine. BBBUUTTT if I set properties to nil in the super class, UIViewControllerWithLoadingView, the application will crash. Particularly right where I set the properties of the sub class to nil. So for right now I just don't set the properties to nil in the superclass, which becomes problematic because the live bytes just keep piling up at run time.

Comment: What is the exception you get on a crash?  (If it doesn't tell you already, use @try/@catch to find out.)

Comment: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x8)" I'm unable to get the description of the exception because the app crashes before I can log it

Comment: Set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions using the Breakpoint navigator **or** put the @try/@catch around the first line of the program (in main.m).

Comment: Still won't print the exception...tried in both simulator and physical device. The app just crashes before printing

Comment: I don't think this exception can be raised by NSException. Certain exceptions can't be caught, objective c doesn't work like Java where it catches anything

Comment: I believe that if it's an exception that's thrown after the app starts to execute `main` it can be caught.  Sometimes apps are killed by signals, however, and sometimes they fail during launch.  Those are tough to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the superclass I had a view that extended uiview which had a property reference to the viewcontroller. Well dealloc is automatically called in arc so dealloc would actually set the viewcontroller itself to nil causing a crash. Once I removed the property of the viewcontroller in the custom view class the problem no longer occurred

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is that methods that "clean up"--like dealloc or viewDidUnload--should make the call to super after they do everything else.  (And methods that "set up"--like init--call to super first.)  I can't tell if that's your problem without seeing all your subclass implementations, but that would be a place to start.

Comment: Although I did have some super calls in the wrong place according to your comments, this still did not fix the problem